# Need suggestion for Telerik Kendo UI JQuery Alternate

Tags: open-source, web-apps, software-development, user-interface, asp.net

My company looking for a Web Application upgrade. Currently, we are using HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, JavaScript, Asp.net core, ASP.NET MVC, dhtmlx Scheduler, and Bootstrap V3. I went through the entire App and my suggestion is Telerik Kendo UI JQuery. Kendo UI fulfills my Entire Web App requirements but it's too costly. Can you suggest to me any alternate Free or low-cost with high user-friendly MIT Licensed items?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Syncfusion UI Component Suite

Essential Studio is a software package that provides state-of-the-art solutions for startups and enterprises. It includes more than 1,800 components and frameworks for WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET (MVC, Core), UWP, WinUI, .NET MAUI, Xamarin, Flutter, Blazor, JavaScript, Angular, Vue, and React that make developers’ work easier.

https://www.syncfusion.com/

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion